# checking which window is active in a Linux script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-10.04, script

In a Linux bash script I can do several things with windows using wmctrl but I'm trying to figure out how to determine what the currently active window is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call wmctrl, instead of passing the window's identifier string as an argument, pass the special string ":ACTIVE:" (without the quotes) and it will apply to the currently active window.

However, this does not seem to return the actual name of the window, and so may not be the answer you are looking for.